# Alexander duality and simplicial complexes

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, planar-graphs

A consequence of Alexander duality is the fact that an $n$-dimensional simplicial complex $K$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ separates $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ into $\beta_n + 1$ connected components where $\beta_n$ is the dimension of $H_n(K)$.

When $K$ is a 1-dimensional complex embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $K$ is a planar graph. It is well known that the edges in a planar embedding belong to at most two faces of the embedding. That is, the 1-simplices in $K$ belong to the boundaries of at most two connected components of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus K$.

Does the statement for planar graphs hold in higher dimensions? If $K$ is an $n$-dimensional complex embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is it true that the $n$-simplices of $K$ belong to the boundaries of at most two connected components of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus K$?

Comment: Do you assume your embedding to be PL, or your complex to be finite?

Comment: I assume the complex to be finite. It does not necessarily need to be PL, but I would still find a result about PL complexes to be very interesting.

Comment: Can you give some hint as to what issues might arise? I am struggling to understand why this is not totally obvious from the fact that an $n$-simplex in $R^{n+1}$ has two sides (say locally around the barycenter of the simplex it looks like a hyperplane in $R^{n+1}$).

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if it could be easily proved by that argument, however I'm not experienced enough in this domain to see how to write a formal proof.